# Changing Account Owner and Type Based on Criteria

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I am trying to change Account owner and NewType(custom field on Account) using trigger based on the values of two custom fields OnLeave(check box) and NumberOfDaysOnLeave(Number) created on User(standard object). But trigger is not getting fired as expected.

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger UserGoingLeave on User (before update,before insert) {
User userOnLeave = Trigger.new[0];
List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,NewType__c,OwnerId FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :userOnLeave.Id];
if(userOnLeave.OnLeave__c == TRUE){
    for(Account a: acc){
        AccountManagement.changeTypeOrOwner(a, userOnLeave);
    }
}   
}
```

**Apex class:**

```
public class AccountManagement{

//Function to change Type of Account or A
public static void changeTypeOrOwner(Account acc, User us){
    if(us.NumberOfDaysOnLeave__c > 90 && us.NumberOfDaysOnLeave__c <= 180){     // When leave is for less than 90 days
        acc.NewType__c = 'Former Client';
    }
    else if(us.NumberOfDaysOnLeave__c > 180){    //When leave is for more than 180 days
        If(us.DelegatedApproverId == null){      // When use has no delegated approver
            acc.NewType__c = 'Deactivated';
        }
        else{                                    //When user has delegated approver  
            acc.OwnerId = us.DelegatedApproverId;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in your code.

1. You are processing only the first user. should *consider bulk* user modification.
2. Move the **SQOL** into the `IF(userOnLeave.OnLeave__c == TRUE)`
3. You need to add the `update acc;` after modify it.
4. You probably should change your method to return the updated account and make the update DML operation bulk-safe:

   ```
    public class AccountManagement{

       //Function to change Type of Account or A
       public static Account changeTypeOrOwner(Account acc, User us){
           if(us.NumberOfDaysOnLeave__c > 90 && us.NumberOfDaysOnLeave__c <= 180){     // When leave is for less than 90 days
               acc.NewType__c = 'Former Client';
           }
           else if(us.NumberOfDaysOnLeave__c > 180){    //When leave is for more than 180 days
               If(us.DelegatedApproverId == null){      // When use has no delegated approver
                   acc.NewType__c = 'Deactivated';
               }
               else{                                    //When user has delegated approver  
                   acc.OwnerId = us.DelegatedApproverId;
               }
           }
           //ADD THIS LINE:
           return acc;
       }
       }
   ```

   **Trigger class:**

   trigger UserGoingLeave on User (before update,before insert) {
           User userOnLeave = Trigger.new[0];

   ```
   if(userOnLeave.OnLeave__c == TRUE){
       List<Account> acc = new Account[]{};
       for(Account a: [SELECT Id,NewType__c,OwnerId FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :userOnLeave.Id]){
           acc.add(AccountManagement.changeTypeOrOwner(a, userOnLeave));
       }
       update acc; //THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT!
     }   
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help Martin. Can you tell me how can implement consider bulk user modification?

Comment: Well, to make it bulk-safe and consider a massive user change, the first thing you have to do is change this: User userOnLeave = Trigger.new[0]; to a map which contains only the usersOnLeave flag in true. After that you should query the accounts using that map, and finally use also the map to get the user to pass to changeTypeOrOwner.

Comment: Is it advisable to use SOQL for loop inside another for loop?Is it against best practices?(Please see the trigger I posted below). Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

This my final trigger.Thanks @Martin Borthiry

```
trigger UserGoingLeave on User (before update) {
Set<User> usersOnLeave = new Set<User>{};
for(User us :Trigger.new){
    if(us.OnLeave__c == TRUE){
        usersOnLeave.add(us);
    }
}

List<Account> accList = new List<Account>([SELECT Id,OwnerId FROM Account WHERE OwnerId IN :usersOnLeave]);
List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>{};

for(User us :usersOnLeave){
    for(Account acc :accList){
        if(acc.OwnerId== us.Id){
            accToUpdate.add(AccountManagement.changeTypeOrOwner(acc, us));
        }
    }
}

update accToUpdate;

}
```

Comment: Avoid to do that, build a User Map in a first for, and then query the accounts. For that query result make a second for. NEVER, use a SOQL into a loop

Comment: Can you give a code sample on the above @MartinBorthiry.